# Set Column Type for IDataReader

Tags: c#, .net, odbc, sqlbulkcopy, datareader

I'm parsing a csv with an IDataReader that will be used for a SqlBulkCopy operation. The destination table for the SqlBulkCopy has a column with type "Time". The bulk copy fails because it's trying to cast a DateTime to a TimeSpan. When I investigate the IDataReader, I find that the IDataReader is parsing the the "transactionTime" column as a DateTime instead of a Time. How can I get the IDataReader to parse "transactionTime" as a Time or TimeSpan so that the SqlBulkCopy will work?

```
var csvFile = $"{blobSource}.csv";
string connectionString =
    "DSN=testcsv;" + // This is an ODBC Data Source that uses Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)
    $"Dbq={LoadConstants.InputFilesDir};" +
    "Extensions=csv";

using (var con = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    var cmdText = $@"SELECT * FROM [{csvFile}]";

    using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand(cmdText, con))
    {
        using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the "TestTimeCol.txt" file

```
transactionTime
11:11:11
```

This is a dump of the "schema" variable. IDataReader is parsing the column as a DateTime

[image: This is a dump of the schema variable. IDataReader is parsing the column as a DateTime]

This is the error thrown by SqlBulkCopy

[image: This is the error thrown by SqlBulkCopy]

My "testcsv" data source uses the Microsoft Text Driver

[image: The data source and its driver]

Comment: You are using in the connection string either ACE driver or JET driver.  These drivers are the backend that excel uses and the default type is GENERAL where the driver attempts to guess the type and often make errors.  Try adding IMEX=1 to the connection string which forces the driver to treat fields as string.  See : https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Comment: @jdweng adding IMEX=1 to the connection string didn't have an impact on the data type of transactionTime. I should point out that my data source is using the Microsoft text driver, not the excel driver. I added a screenshot to my question.

Comment: The Microsoft Text Driver is ODBC which was replaced with OleDb (Jet).  I have an old MS-Dos Encyclopedia that recommends using Oledb instead of ODBC for new applications.  Actually in some cases ODBC is better than OleDb.  Oracle still uses a ODBC driver.  What is the destination database?  How do you have to column defined?

Comment: You can use a mapping.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopycolumnmapping?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @jdweng The destination db is Sql Server. The column is defined as type Time in the destination table.

Comment: @jdweng Unfortunately, ColumnMappings don't support typecasts, they just map columns between tables, my columns are already mapped correctly, but the source column is the wrong type.